# Best way to CREATE a SQL Server table via flat file schema?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a flat file table schema (tab delimited) from another type of database (I don't know what type), but it gives me the basics of what I need such as column name, data type, description. This table has many columns.

What is the best way to create a table in SQL Server 2008 from this flat file?

Comment: you can import that into a table and generate create statements using columns from that and run that as a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ex:

You can import file into a table with following columns

```
TableA:
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DESCRIPTION
```

Then generate create statement using script below and copy output and save as sql script

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (' + cols + ')' FROM  (
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + s.COLUMN_NAME + ' ' DATA_TYPE
FROM tableA s WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS Cols) A
```

Comment: rs, the first part was right (TableA), but I am getting the following syntax error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near ')'. Thoughts?

Comment: fixed: it was missing alias for subquery.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change it up a bit in order to just spit out a "CREATE TABLE" statement, but this solution did the trick!